# Redstone Circuitry - Resistors?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

Is there any way to construct a resistor within a redstone circuit? I was thinking that there might be some properties of cobblestone versus glass, dirt versus obsidian, etc. but I haven't had the opportunity to check it out. Is there any data on this?

(I realize that there probably aren't resistors in Minecraft YET, but i'm really hoping i'm wrong)

Comment: What are you hoping to use the resistor to do? That might get more answers, especially as I'm betting most folks aren't electrical engineers.

Comment: Which is to say -- though we might know what a resistor *does*, we haven't a clue why they're so darn *useful*.

Comment: They aren't particularly useful for binary circuits like redstone emulates.  For analog circuits, however, they are important to limit current, among other things.

Comment: I'm wildly fantasizing about constructing a working synth, to be completely meta and make video game music in a video game. resistors are the first step out of many.

Comment: @Raven: Speak for yourself :-) I'm sure I'm not the only one here whose other hobbies include electronics..

Answer (score 17, accepted):

No; redstone can be used to emulate [logic gates](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logic_gate), not electrical components.  There is no analog to *any* electrical component, nor any use for them.

---

If what you want is to slow down/delay the signal *(which is **not** what resistors do)*, you can use a [redstone repeater](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Redstone_Repeater).

Answer (score 5):

You can use a Redstone Comparator to produce a desired signal strength. When set to subtract mode, the signal being produced out the front will equal the back input minus the side input.

Therefore if you have a repeater directly behind the comparator (15 signal strength), and a lever with two pieces of dust going into the side (14 signal strength) the comparator will output 1 signal strength.

If the comparator has two side inputs, it will simply use the most powerful one.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a circuit which is analogous to a capacitor using two comparators, some redstone dust, and some opaque blocks, but even they don't work exactly like real capacitors. I guess the closest analogous circuit I could think of to a resistor would be a comparator set for subtraction mode with another comparator feeding into it's side reading a set value from a chest. That way it can subtract a set value from an analog input. Obviously still not quite the same or really all that similar even, but I think it is about as close as you can get. You can even use an item frame instead of the chest to make it a variable resister, though I think you would actually need two if you wanted the full range of resistances (0-15), and you would need to subtract one from each before inputting them because item frames don't have a 0 output with comparators.

Of course this might not be terribly useful to you since it still won't work quite the same as a resistor in the real world.

Answer (score -2):

Why not use command blocks?
A simple /setblock command should do it.